# Dynamic Filtering on Non-Default View of Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, filter, view, library

Is it possible to filter a Document Library by a List without going back to the default view prior filtering?

I have 2 views, one for Current Year documents and the other containing All documents. Default view is Current Year, but sometimes I want to filter All documents instead of just the current one.

However, upon filtering, it goes back to the Current Year View. I tried changing view prior filtering, and vice versa, it really doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, after you set filter in a non-default view, then you refresh the page, the page will back to the default view.